# Fig layout made tighter interactively by clicking 'adjustment' -> 'tight layout' many times, but unable to reproduce it in my code

Tags: python, matplotlib, layout, subplot

A strange thing is happening. **I am interactively changing how tight the figure is after showing a plot**, by clicking 'adjustment' ->  'tight layout' many times. I know I could copy the 6 parameters and use them to put in my code `fig.subplots_adjust()`, but **the thing is that the layout changes, but there is a point in which the parameters do not!! So, I'm unable to reproduce the effect ...**. Here I'll show you what I mean:

In my code, I've `plt.tight_layout()` before `plt.show()`.

- Here is the outcome I got:

[image]

- Now, I click on 'tight layout'. Parameters change, and the subplots look bigger and nearer:

[image]

- Again, parameters change, and the subplots look bigger and nearer:

[image]

- Again, subplots are nearer **BUT only one parameter changed, and the change is almost meaningless - top was 0.950, and now it's 0.951**:

[image]

- Now, if I export the values and put before `plt.show()`

```py
    plt.subplots_adjust(
              top=0.95,
              bottom=0.062,
              left=0.012,
              right=0.988,
              hspace=0.249,
              wspace=0.0)
```

I get:

[image]

**The figure is not as tight as I wanted it to be!! And the subplots aren't as big as I want!! I put the exact same parameters. Anyone knows how to solve it?**

---

**TOY EXAMPLE TO REPRODUCE THE ISSUE:**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
limit = 3
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=limit, ncols=limit, sharex=True, sharey=True, )

for i in range(limit):
    for j in range(limit):
        ax = axes[i, j]
        ax.set_xbound(lower=-2, upper=2)
        ax.set_ybound(lower=-2, upper=2)
        ax.grid()
        ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

# show
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.canvas.manager.window.showMaximized()
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Test')
plt.tight_layout() # TODO: comment this line to see the difference if tight layout is not specified

# TODO: uncomment the following block to see that nothing happens if tight layout and the parameters are set
# plt.subplots_adjust(
#   top=0.951,
#   bottom=0.062,
#   left=0.012,
#   right=0.988,
#   hspace=0.249,
#   wspace=0.0
# )
plt.show()
```

**Side note:** I'm currently using `matplotlib 3.1.1`

Comment: Interesting, but I fear one cannot help here without an actual [mcve] that shows the issue.

Comment: Yes, I know! The thing is that the way the subplots are generated is kind of complicated. I will edit my question with a toy example.

Comment: I also wonder about the title not being centered. This could be something that plays into the observed behaviour.

Comment: Ok, I will fix it!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest hey! I updated my question. Check out the toy example - even if you set the parameters, you get the same result as if you didn't ..

Comment: The subplot parameters that you specify are the ones you get as a result from pressing the tight layout button. Is that correct? If so, it would totally make sense that the result is the same in both cases.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the **parameters** I copy and paste, are **the ones I obtain after pressing the tight layout button many times**. The problem, is that even if I specify those parameters, **I do not get the layout as tight as I saw it the last time** I pressed the tight layout button.

Comment: I see. There is a free parameter, which tight layout does not take into account, and that is the positon of the box within the space that is available in case an aspect is set for the axes. Maybe call tight_layout once, then set the `left` and `right` parameter manually.